# If $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n \subset B$ does it imply $A_m \subset B$ for $m$ large enough?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_i$ be a sequence of non-empty monotonic decreasing open and bounded subsets $A_1\supset A_2\supset \cdots$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a non-empty intersection.
If the intersection is compactly embedded in an open subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e.
$$\cap_{i=1}^\infty A_i \subset \subset B$$
does it imply $A_m \subset B$ for $m$ large enough?

Comment: You can consider $B$ of any "nice shape" (like a disc or an open rectangle), let's say a vertically placed rectangle for this example. Take $A$ the open upper half of $B$, and picture $A_i$ a sequence of open rectangles decreasing to $A$ from above. You can make this rigorous but that's the gist of it: your claim won't hold even with non-empty intersection. Your claim should hold if the distance between the intersection of the $A_i$s and the boundary of $B$ is positive though.

Comment: Thanks for that example! I have made my question more precise: I think of an intersection whose closure is contained in the open set $B$

Comment: It's clear why you would "want" this to be true.  Every point $x\not\in B$ is eventually (for sufficiently large $m$) not in $A_m$. But you can't move the quantifier and conclude that eventually (for sufficiently large $m$) every point $x\not\in B$ is not in $A_m$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n=1$, let $A_i=(1-i^{-1},1)$, let $B=(3,4)$. Then the $A_i$ are non-empty, monotonic decreasing, open, and bounded, their intersection is empty and thus a subset of $B$, but no $A_i$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to rule out an empty intersection, and have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Then add $(9,10)$ to each $A_i$ and to $B$.

Answer (score 2):

One dimensional example:

Let $A_{n}=(-\frac1n,\frac1n)\cup (1,1+\frac1n)$, $B=(-\frac12,\frac12)$.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, take $A_i$ (for $i=1,2,3,\ldots$) to be the points
$$
\{(r,\theta):r < 1 \vee (r\in[1,2) \; \wedge \; \theta\in(0,\pi/i))\}.
$$
In other words, the open unit circle plus an ever-decreasing wedge of the open circle with radius $2$.  The intersection is just the open unit circle, but no $A_m$ is fully contained in it.